# Relating vertex buffers and vertex attributes in openGL

Tags: linux, opengl

My entire code that is supposed to draw a triangle on the screen is:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

#include <string.h>


const GLint WIDTH=800, HEIGHT=600;
GLuint VAO, VBO, shader;

//Vertex Shader
/*static const char**/
const GLchar* vShader = "\n"
"\n"
"#version 330 \n"
"layout (location=0) in vec3 pos;\n"
"void main(){\n"
"gl_Position = vec4(pos.x,pos.y,pos.z,1.0);\n"
"\n"
"}\n"
"";

// fragment shader
const GLchar* fShader = "\n"
"#version 330 \n"
"out vec4 colour;\n"
"void main(){\n"
"colour = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"\n";

void CreateTriangle(){
    GLfloat vertices[] = {
        -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
        1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
        0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f
    };

    // vertex arrays
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glBindVertexArray(VAO);
    // vertex buffers
    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,VBO);

        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,sizeof(GLfloat)*9,vertices,GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        glVertexAttribPointer(0,3, GL_FLOAT,GL_FALSE,0, 0);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

     glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
     glBindVertexArray(0);
}

void AddShader(GLuint theProgram, const GLchar* shaderCode, GLenum shaderType){
    GLuint theShader = glCreateShader(shaderType);

    const GLchar* theCode[1];
    theCode[0] = shaderCode;

    GLint codeLength[1];
    codeLength[0] = strlen(shaderCode);

    glShaderSource(theShader, 1, theCode, codeLength);
    glCompileShader(theShader);

    GLint result=0;
    GLchar eLog[1024]={};

    glGetShaderiv(theShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &result);
    if(!result){
        glGetShaderInfoLog(theShader,sizeof(eLog),NULL, eLog);
        std::cout<< "Error compiling"<<shaderType<<" "<<eLog <<std::endl;
        return;
    }

    glAttachShader(theProgram,theShader);

}

void CompileShader(){
    shader = glCreateProgram();

    if(!shader){
        std::cout<<"Error Creating Shader Program";
        return;
    }

    AddShader(shader, vShader,GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    AddShader(shader, fShader,GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

    // getting error codes
    GLint result=0;
    GLchar eLog[1024]={0};

    // Creates the executables in the graphic card
    glLinkProgram(shader);

    // get information if program is linked properly
    glGetProgramiv(shader, GL_LINK_STATUS, &result);
    if(!result){
        glGetProgramInfoLog(shader,sizeof(eLog),NULL,eLog);
        std::cout<<"Error linking program"<<eLog<<std::endl;
        return;
    }

    glValidateProgram(shader);
    glGetProgramiv(shader,GL_VALIDATE_STATUS,&result);
    if(!result){
        glGetProgramInfoLog(shader, sizeof(eLog),NULL, eLog);
        std::cout<<"Error validating program"<<eLog<<std::endl;
        return;
    }

}

int main(void){
    if(!glfwInit()){
        std::cout << "glfw initialization failed" << std::endl;
        glfwTerminate();
        return 1;
    }

    // glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR,3);
    // glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR,3);

    // glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    // glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);

    GLFWwindow *mainWindow = glfwCreateWindow(WIDTH, HEIGHT, "NEW WINDOW", NULL, NULL);

    if(!mainWindow){
        std::cout<< "Window creation failed" <<std::endl;
        glfwTerminate();
        return 1;
    }


    int bufferWidth, bufferHeight;
    glfwGetFramebufferSize(mainWindow, &bufferWidth, &bufferHeight);

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(mainWindow);

    if(glewInit() != GLEW_OK){
        std::cout << "GLEW Initialization failed" << std::endl;
        glfwDestroyWindow(mainWindow);
        glfwTerminate();
        return 1;
    }

    glViewport(0,0,bufferWidth, bufferHeight);

    CreateTriangle();
    CompileShader();

    while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(mainWindow)){
        glfwPollEvents();
        glUseProgram(shader);
        glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        glBindVertexArray(VAO);
                glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES,0,3);
        glBindVertexArray(0);
        glUseProgram(0);
        glfwSwapBuffers(mainWindow);
        std::cout<<"something"<<std::endl;
    }

    return 0;

}
```

It essentially draws a black screen and there's no error whatsoever but is supposed to draw a red triangle so I'm trying to debug this code and there is essentially some parts in the code that I don't understand.

1) How does the VBO (Vertex Buffer Object) relate to the VAO (Vertex Attribute object), we basically defined these using the following inside of the `CreateTriangles() function`:

```
...
glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glBindVertexArray(VAO);
    // vertex buffers
    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,VBO);

        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,sizeof(GLfloat)*9,vertices,GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        glVertexAttribPointer(0,3, GL_FLOAT,GL_FALSE,0, 0);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

     glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
     glBindVertexArray(0);
 ...
```

Note that we already unbind both the VAO and VBO, but during the drawing call inside the while loop:

```
while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(mainWindow)){
        glfwPollEvents();
        glUseProgram(shader);
        glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        glBindVertexArray(VAO);
                glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES,0,3);
        glBindVertexArray(0);
        glUseProgram(0);
        glfwSwapBuffers(mainWindow);
        std::cout<<"something"<<std::endl;
    }
```

we only rebind the VAO and not the VBO, which I think may be the result of the error, but I don't know for sure.

Also, the tutorial says that the VBO is bound inside the VAO but I don't see there being any linking or anything that related VBO to the VAO in the code, so I'm really being confused on how is it that we're binding them together and why we're only binding back the VAO and not the VBO during the drawing stage?

I'm using Linux OS and used the following to compile:

```
g++ -std=c++17 main.cpp -o main -lGL -lGLEW -lglfw && ./main
```

Comment: It is sufficient to bind `glBindVertexArray(VAO)`, because the specification of the generic vertex attribute array is stated in the VAO. It's the job of the VAO to know all the information about vertex attributes (and indices). When `glVertexAttribPointer` is called than the a name reference of the current VBO is stored in the current VAO. I can't reproduce the issue, the program works fine for me. I copied your code and didn't have to change any line. By the way, the code even runs in a core profile context (`GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE`).

Comment: it drew a triangle? Really? I use linux and I used the following to compile: `g++ -std=c++17 main.cpp -o main -lGL -lGLEW -lglfw && ./main`, don't know if it'd work on windows but it's supposed to be cross platform right?

Comment: @Rabbid76 , what do you mean by: "because the specification of the generic vertex attribute array is stated in the VAO." and where did I do that in the code? Do you mean `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` , but I specified that in the binding of the VBO and not the VAO.

Comment: When `glVertexAttribPointer` is called than the a name reference of the current VBO is stored in the current VAO. The current VAO is bound by `glBindVertexArray(VAO);` and the current VBO is bound by `glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,VBO);`. `glVertexAttribPointer` associates `VBO` to the resource index 0 in `VAO`. This association is stored in the state vector of `VAO`. So it is sufficient to bind `VAO`(`glBindVertexArray(VAO)`) before the draw call.

Comment: What if we generate multiple VBOs and then call `glBindBuffer` are they all associated to the resource index 0?

Comment: @Rabbid76, and any idea why it doesn't work on linux?

Comment: *"are they all associated to the resource index 0"* - 0 is the attribute resource index (the 1st parameter to `glVertexAttribPointer`).

Comment: *"and any idea why it doesn't work on linux? "* No. Are your drivers up to date? Do you use the most recent version of [glfw](https://www.glfw.org/) and [glew](http://glew.sourceforge.net/)?

Comment: @Rabbid76, my drivers are up to date, and glfw and glew are also upto date

Comment: @Rabbid76 , I think that answer was correct. my code didn't work without the flag set to `GL_TRUE` and the docs don't say anything about it either

Comment: No, probably you don't use the most recent [gelw](http://glew.sourceforge.net/) version (2.1.0). I verified it just now, `glewExperimental = GL_TRUE` is not necessary.

Comment: @Rabbid76 , okay. But, do you mind telling me how did you find that? It isnt written in the doc, is it?

Comment: [glew Supported Extensions](http://glew.sourceforge.net/): *"The latest release contains support for OpenGL 4.6, compatibility and forward-compatible contexts and the following extensions:"*

Answer (score 0):

From comments above, credit to @Rabbid76:

When glVertexAttribPointer is called than the a name reference of the current VBO is stored in the current VAO. The current VAO is bound by glBindVertexArray(VAO); and the current VBO is bound by glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,VBO);. glVertexAttribPointer associates VBO to the resource index 0 in VAO. This association is stored in the state vector of VAO. So it is sufficient to bind VAO(glBindVertexArray(VAO)) before the draw call. Hence, only binding the VAO is sufficient.

As for the problem stated in the comments regarding the black screen try
Updating the glew version and your graphic card drive. If updating glew is not possible, then just set the `glExperimental=GL_TRUE`.